# SSD turned to RAW suddenly - Reliable?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery, filesystem-corruption, raw

My laptop with Windows 10 fall creators update (installed one week ago) is running on a laptop with the main disk SSD OCZ Vertex 128GB + a secondary internal disk Samsung SSD 512GB, the latter as a replacement for the DVD drive ,using a suitable caddy (DELL Latitude E6520).

Today, all of a sudden after a reboot, the secondary disk wasn't accessible, while the unit was visible in Windows Explorer showing the correct amount of used data and free space, however attempting to accessing the unit would throw an error "The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error"; attempting to CHKDSK would state that the filesystem is RAW.

I have run SMART test getting the following attached results. 
Then I have run Easus recovery tools, that found a lot of files but not all. Quite worried I have accessed the disk that in the meanwhile recovered. Back to NTFS, fully accessible no errors given  by CHKDSK.

I wonder why all this happened, and if the unit is reliable or not.

Your thoughts?

EDIT:

Found many articles such [as this one](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/6-reasons-solutions-external-drive-suddenly-becomes-raw/) stating that this sudden change may occur for bad connections or power outage. I wonder if I can rely on this disk and the computer itself

EDIT 2:

The problem occurred again. Downloaded Samsung Magician, no errors detected on the unit, I suspect the problem lies in the controller or the operating system. I have unplugged the caddy & removed the hard disk, connecting it to an external USB cable. Currently testing. I wonder if it may happen that the internal controller gets defective?

EDIT 3:

Now on day 2 with the disk connected externally through USB cable. No glitches and one other important aspect: the laptop keyboard was stopping working in the last months and had to power off and on the computer to set it back to work. Since I have removed the disk from the caddy, this is not happening anymore. Could the caddy be defective? Or the controller? Or maybe the internal disk was draining too much energy from the controller?

```
*** DiskCheckup V3.4 Build: 1003 Report ***

SysInfo DLL Version:                                                  SysInfo v1.0 Build: 1122
Time of export:                                                       17:38:13 02-mar-2018

Device information:                                                   
   Device ID:                                                         1
   Interface:                                                         SATA
   Device Capacity:                                                   476937 MB
   Serial Number:                                                     S2RBNCAJ186494B
   Model Number:                                                      Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB
   Firmware Revision:                                                 EMT02B6Q
   Partitions:                                                        
      E:         476837 MB

ATA information:                                                      

   Disk geometry:                                                     
      Cylinders:                                                      60801
      Tracks/Cylinder:                                                255
      Sectors/Track:                                                  63
      Bytes/Sector:                                                   512
      Total disk sectors:                                             976773168
      Logical sector size:                                            512
      Physical sector size:                                           512
      Media rotation rate:                                            SSD
      Buffer size:                                                    N/A
      ECC size:                                                       N/A

   Standards compliance:                                              
      ATA8-ACS Supported:                                             Yes
      ATA/ATAPI-7 Supported:                                          Yes
      ATA/ATAPI-6 Supported:                                          Yes
      ATA/ATAPI-5 Supported:                                          Yes
      ATA/ATAPI-4 Supported:                                          Yes
      SATA Compliance:                                                Yes
         SATA Gen3 Signaling Speed (6.0Gb/s) Supported:               Yes
         SATA Gen2 Signaling Speed (3.0Gb/s) supported:               Yes
         SATA Gen1 Signaling Speed (1.5Gb/s) supported:               Yes
      Transport Type:                                                 Serial
         SATA 3.0 Transport Compilance:                               Yes
         SATA 2.6 Transport Compilance:                               Yes
         SATA 2.5 Transport Compilance:                               Yes
         SATA II: Ext Transport Compilance:                           Yes
         SATA 1.0a Transport Compilance:                              Yes
         ATA8-AST Transport Compilance:                               Yes
   World Wide ID:                                                     5002538D704CB9DD

   Feature support:                                                   
      SMART supported:                                                Yes
         SMART enabled:                                               Yes
      SMART self-test supported:                                      Yes
      SMART error log supported:                                      Yes
      LBA supported:                                                  Yes
      IORDY supported:                                                Yes
      CFast supported:                                                No
      DMA supported:                                                  Yes
         Maximum Multiword DMA mode supported:                        2
         Multiword DMA selected:                                      None
         Maximum UltraDMA mode supported:                             6
         UltraDMA selected:                                           5
      Maximum PIO mode supported:                                     4
      SATA Compliance:                                                Yes
         NCQ priority information supported:                          No
         Unload while NCQ commands are outstanding supported:         No
         Phy Event Counters supported:                                Yes
         Receipt of power management requests supported:              No
         NCQ feature set supported:                                   Yes
         Software Settings Preservation:                              Supported, Enabled
         In-order data delivery:                                      Not supported
         Initiating power management:                                 Supported, Disabled
         DMA Setup auto-activation:                                   Supported, Disabled
         Non-zero buffer offsets:                                     Not supported
      Trusted Computing supported:                                    Yes
      Host Protected Area (HPA) supported:                            Yes
      Read look-ahead supported:                                      Yes
         Read look-ahead enabled:                                     Yes
      Write cache supported:                                          Yes
         Write cache enabled:                                         Yes
      Power management supported:                                     Yes
      Security mode supported:                                        Yes
         Security mode enabled:                                       No
      Device Configuration Overlay (DCO) supported:                   Yes
      48bit Addressing supported:                                     Yes
      Auto Acoustic Managment (AAM) supported:                        No
      Power-up in Standby (PUIS) supported:                           No
      Advanced Power Management (APM) supported:                      No
      CompactFlash Association (CFA) supported:                       No
      General Purpose Logging (GPL) supported:                        Yes
      Streaming supported:                                            No
      Media card pass through supported:                              No
      Extended power conditions supported:                            No
      Extended status reporting supported:                            No
      Write-read-verify supported:                                    Yes
         Write-read-verify enabled:                                   No
      Free-fall control supported:                                    No
      TRIM command supported:                                         Yes
      SCT command transport supported:                                Yes
      NV Cache enabled:                                               No
      NV Cache Power Management supported:                            No

SMART ATTRIBUTES:
 ID Description                             Status      Value       Worst       Threshold   Raw Value   TEC                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  5 Reallocated Sector Count                OK          100         100         10          0           N/A                 
  9 Power On Time                           OK          99          99          0           1354        N/A                 
 12 Power Cycle Count                       OK          99          99          0           688         N/A                 
177 Used Reserved Block Count (Chip)        OK          99          99          0           2           N/A                 
179 Used Reserved Block Count (Total)       OK          100         100         10          0           N/A                 
181 Program Fail Count (Total)              OK          100         100         10          0           N/A                 
182 Erase Fail Count (Total)                OK          100         100         10          0           N/A                 
183 Runtime bad block (Total)               OK          100         100         10          0           N/A                 
187 Reported Uncorrectable Errors           OK          100         100         0           0           N/A                 
190 Air Flow temperature                    OK          63          47          0           37          N/A                 
195 ECC Error Rate                          OK          200         200         0           0           N/A                 
199 UltraDMA CRC Error Count                OK          100         100         0           0           N/A                 
235 Power Recovery Count                    OK          99          99          0           10          N/A                 
241 Total LBAs Written                      OK          99          99          0           2584173079  N/A                 

SMART HISTORY:
Attribute ID: 5     Attribute Name: Reallocated Sector Count
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 9     Attribute Name: Power On Time
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 12    Attribute Name: Power Cycle Count
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 177   Attribute Name: Used Reserved Block Count (Chip)
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 179   Attribute Name: Used Reserved Block Count (Total)
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 181   Attribute Name: Program Fail Count (Total)
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 182   Attribute Name: Erase Fail Count (Total)
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 183   Attribute Name: Runtime bad block (Total)
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 187   Attribute Name: Reported Uncorrectable Errors
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 190   Attribute Name: Air Flow temperature
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 195   Attribute Name: ECC Error Rate
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 199   Attribute Name: UltraDMA CRC Error Count
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 235   Attribute Name: Power Recovery Count
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history

Attribute ID: 241   Attribute Name: Total LBAs Written
                     Date   Value       Worst       Raw       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No history
```

Comment: I wonder if this glitch happened for a faulty controller or interface in the computer or a bug in the OS or if the SSD is defective

Comment: Edited my questions

Comment: Other edit...............

Comment: 3rd edit........................

Comment: There's no need to comment after each edit unless, for example, you are pinging another user who has asked for further information.

Comment: Thanks! Will users be notified about edits?

Comment: They can see edits [here](https://superuser.com/posts/1299892/revisions)... but won't get notifications unless you message them.

Answer (score 3):

If you value your data, stop using that drive.  I had one of those a few years ago that randomly started throwing fileystem corruption.  On close inspection, it appeared to be randomly reassigning the contents of one sector to another, causing parts of some of my text files to appear inside what should have been a directory entry.  This happened several times before I took the drive out of service.

I will not trust OCZ with my data again.